# Kadane algorithm implementation returns incorrect result

Tags: java, algorithm, kadanes-algorithm

I have written Kadane's algorithm but somehow it returns incorrect result. Not sure why. Here is the implementation. It is basically to find the `ubarray with maximum sum in an array

```
public class Kadane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr =  {-2, -5, 6, -2, -3, 1, 5, -6};
        Kadane k = new Kadane();
        System.out.println(k.calculate(arr, 0, 0));
    }

    public int calculate(int[] arr, int pointer, int sum) {
        if(pointer >= arr.length )
            return sum;

        return Math.max(calculate(arr, pointer+1, sum+arr[pointer]), calculate(arr, pointer+1, 0));
    }
}
```

I suppose it should somehow return the max sum which is 7. In the computation I see 7 being calculated but it return 1. Is there any fundamental thing I am missing in the code?

I have read other implementations and they make sense as well, just not getting my head around on why is it not returning the correct answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you passing sum as a parameter?  Why are you making 2 recursive calls? I can't really tell how you expect this to work.  It's not a lot like Kadane's algorithm

Comment: you are trying to create some way more complex solution for straight forward Kadane's algorithm, but still I would suggest that you take some smaller input like with 2-3 elements in array and then dry run your code making a recursion tree,

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this recursively?  A normal implementation is O(n) so why complicate it with recursive calls?

Comment: @WJS: Just practising my skills, was aware of other implementations but was just polishing skills.

Comment: That's an excellent reason.  More folks should do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not accounting for the fact that you may have already found the sum you want. Thus, you need:

```
return Math.max(sum, Math.max(calculate(arr, pointer+1, sum+arr[pointer]), calculate(arr, pointer+1, 0)));
```